# function bind_param() on a non-object in my new code

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to change my PHP code into another secure one so I change the update.PHP page [from this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33560398/how-to-prevent-sql-injections-by-updating-codes/) to that:

```
<?php 
require_once ('../include/global.php');
$id=$_REQUEST['id']; 

  if (isset ($_POST['name'])) { 
$name = $_POST['name']; 
} 
if (isset ($_POST['remarcs'])) { 
$remarcs = $_POST['remarcs']; 
} 
if (isset ($_POST['test_res'])) { 
$test_res = $_POST['test_res']; 
} 
if (isset ($_POST['address'])) { 
$address = $_POST['address']; 
} 

if (isset ($_POST['date'])) { 
$date = $_POST['date']; 
} 

if (isset ($_POST['phone_num'])) { 
$phone = $_POST['phone_num']; 
}

if (isset ($_POST['illness'])) { 
$illness = $_POST['illness']; 
} 
if (isset ($_POST['echo'])) { 
$echo = $_POST['echo']; 
} 
if (isset ($_POST['pe'])) { 
$pe = $_POST['pe']; 
} 
if (isset ($_POST['pmhx'])) { 
$pmhx = $_POST['pmhx']; 
} 
if (isset ($_POST['pshx'])) { 
$pshx = $_POST['pshx']; 
} 
if (isset ($_POST['habbits'])) { 
$habbits = $_POST['habbits']; 
} 
if (isset ($_POST['occup'])) { 
$occup = $_POST['occup']; 
} 
if (isset ($_POST['allergy'])) { 
$allergy = $_POST['allergy']; 
} 

//Check file is uploaded or not 
//if (isset($_FILES['file']['name']) && $_FILES['file']['name']!='' && $_FILES['file']['error']=='') {
//$path2 = ... ; 
//move_uploaded_file(...);
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]))
{
    $path = "../uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path);
        $new_path = "./uploads/".$path;

}
else{
    $new_path = $_POST['org_path'];
//$path2 = "../uploads/".$_FILES['echo_photo']['name']; 
}
$sql=('UPDATE $tbl_name SET name = ?, 
echo_files = ?, 
remarcs = ?,
test_res = ?, 
date = ?, 
address = ?, 
phone_num = ?,
illness = ?,
echo = ?, 
pmhx = ?, 
pshx = ?, 
habbits = ?, 
occup = ?, 
allergy = ?,
pe = ?
WHERE id = ? ');
$stmt= $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssssssi", $name, $path, $remarcs, $test_res, $date, $address, $phone,
$illness, $echo, $pmhx, $pshx, $habbits, $occup, $allergy, $pe, $id);
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->errno){
echo "FAILURE!!! " . $stmt->error;
}
 else { 
header("location:update_done.php");
}
?>
```

Now I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in
>   So any help with this ?

Comment: Where is `$con` set ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because You are not define `$tbl_name` in your code

```
$sql=('UPDATE $tbl_name SET name = ?,.....
```

It will produce

```
UPDATE  SET name = ?...
```

Try to set your table name

Comment: Ok Thanks that's it. But I am confused, I am already defined $tbl_name in the connection file and include it into the page, why it ddn't take it from their @Saty

Comment: Yes, I am but why it didnt take it from their ?

Comment: just remove $ use `tbl_name` and check

Comment: no it does not get it from their, it says an error: clinic.tbl_name does not exist and when I use $tbl_name it says clinic.$tbl_name does not exist

Comment: But it can get $con from the included file, wow how is that now

Comment: Put your query inside double quotes

Comment: which one ? The sql statement ?

Comment: Yes now it takes it when I did that: $sql=("UPDATE $tbl_name..."

Comment: something like `$sql="UPDATE ".tbl_name." SET name...";`

Answer (score 1):

`prepare()` method returns false if there is an error as stated [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). You should keep it in an `if` statement.

Your query string will not interpret the variable `$tbl_name` because you are using single quotes. It could be fixed with `'.$tbl_name.'`.

Answer (score 1):

Update your code to this.

```
$stmt= $con->prepare($sql) OR die('Some error occured');
```

Now if it dies, try debugging your code.