# difference between vulnerable code and secure code

Tags: php, sql

I made those 2 posts to improve my code, but can someone can explain to me what is the difference between [this php vulnerable code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33526142/unable-to-find-what-is-the-error-of-php-update) and [this secure code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33561547/function-bind-param-on-a-non-object-in-my-new-code).
I know the first one is insecure and can be subject to SQL injections and the other no, but why this type of coding is strong ?

Comment: dont know what answer you are looking for, *once you know the oven can be very hot you will always use the gloves*.

Comment: Because if you do not bind your parameters, you are vulnerable to [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to be:

Q: Why is a parameterized query less vulnerable than a "raw" query?

Please read this:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Frankly, it should be *MANDATORY READING* for *anybody* interested in "secure coding":

> **Primary Defenses Defense Option 1: Prepared Statements (with Parameterized Queries)**
>
> The use of prepared statements with variable binding (aka
>   parameterized queries) is how all developers should first be taught
>   how to write database queries. They are simple to write, and easier to
>   understand than dynamic queries. Parameterized queries force the
>   developer to first define all the SQL code, and then pass in each
>   parameter to the query later. This coding style allows the database to
>   distinguish between code and data, regardless of what user input is
>   supplied.
>
> Prepared statements ensure that an attacker is not able to change the
>   intent of a query, even if SQL commands are inserted by an attacker.
>   In the safe example below, if an attacker were to enter the userID of
>   tom' or '1'='1, the parameterized query would not be vulnerable and
>   would instead look for a username which literally matched the entire
>   string tom' or '1'='1.

This is just one of many SQL-related issues you should be aware of.  The OWASP article lists others, and has links to many other important topics.

Comment: Okay, and if I am working on a local pho web app for a clinic, security codes is necessary too ?